# How can i properly git a truffle/react project

Tags: truffle

Here is what i've done in a blank directory:

```
$ truffle unbox react
$ npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
$ npm install @openzeppelin/test-helpers
$ npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider
```

Then, i have create a .gitignore (in root directory):

```
build
node_modules
client/src/contracts
```

I have run:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "message"
```

And i have pushed this local git to a github repository

I have cloned the github repository on a second computer.

I need to run this commands again to make runnable my project on the second computer:

```
$ npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
$ npm install @openzeppelin/test-helpers
$ npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider
```

My question is how can i avoid to run this commands ? I have tried to run "npm install" but it does not work. I have no package.json at the root of my project.

Have i made something wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need this:

[Truffle box - React](https://www.trufflesuite.com/boxes/react)

Assuming that you have done the following steps:

- `mkdir myproject`
- `cd myproject`
- `npx truffle unbox react`

After this step you want to create a node project, so you can save your dependencies.

- `npm init`: Keep hitting enter for default values
- `npm install @openzeppelin/contracts`
- `npm install @openzeppelin/test-helpers`
- `npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider`

Now, you can create your `.gitignore` file, and put `node_modules` there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have read this tutorial too but it does not answer to my git clone problem. What i want to know is what i should do after git clone to automaticaly install dependencies

Comment: I misunderstood what you were asking. Check the updated answer.